# Have separate files per button & communicate with various command files when processing Discord's `interactionCreate` event for buttons?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Sorry if this seems vague, I've put as much effort into it as I can.

Discord.JS v13 has an event called [interactionCreate](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-interactionCreate). I am planning on migrating my Discord.JS v12 bot to v13 very soon, but I need to understand how to communicate my `interactionCreate` button events with my command files as well as have separate files for each button before I create my bot.

I don't have any code to show you because I haven't started making the v13 version of my bot, as I need to know this information before I start creating it.

Comment: What exactly do you need to "communicate" between your events and your command files? If your commands need to use buttons, can you not just use [MessageComponent collectors](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createMessageComponentCollector)?

Comment: Nevermind; I didn't know that existed.

Comment: Ah, I figured haha. Yeah, discord.js anticipated this sort of thing by creating their reaction, message, and component collectors. Behind the scenes, the component collector actually does use the `interactionCreate` event, so the collectors have basically already done the work for you when it comes to this question which is pretty nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different ways you could achieve this but here is two ways to do it:

##### Functions for each command:

```js
// index.js

client.on('interactionCreate', (interaction) => {
    if (interaction.isButton()) {
        switch (interaction.customId) {
            case 'command1':
                require('./commands/command1').handleButton(interaction);
                break;
            case 'command2':
                require('./commands/command2').handleButton(interaction);
                break;
            /* etc. */
        }
    }
    /* ... */
});
```

```js
// commands/command1.js

/* command logic */

module.exports.handleButton = (interaction) => {
    /* logic here */
};
```

##### Collectors

You can find the documentation for message component collectors [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createMessageComponentCollector)

```js
// index.js

client.on('interactionCreate', (interaction) => {
    if (interaction.isButton()) {
        return;
    }
    /* ... */
});
```

```js
// commands/command1.js

/* ... */

const collector = message.createMessageComponentCollector({
    filter: (interaction) => {
        /* filter what message component you want to collect 
            for example: */
        return interaction.message.id === message.id;
    }
});

collector.on('collect', (interaction) => {
    /* button logic here */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [MessageComponent collectors](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createMessageComponentCollector) to respond to interactions via a command file; no need to use `interactionCreate` for this.